# how to know when NSData's initWithContentsOfURL has finished loading.

Tags: iphone

I am loading some text from xml and an image, that image takes longer to load than the xml, but I want to show them at the same time.

I am loading the image using

```
NSData *mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgLink]];
```

How can I set a callback function that lets me know that `mydata` has the image, so I can add both the image and the text to the view?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to use NSURLConnection.  This is fairly straightforward, but more involved than the NSData method.

First, create an NSURLConnection:

```
NSMutableData *receivedData;

NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgLink]
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                      timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

 if (theConnection) {
    receivedData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // inform the user that the download could not be made
}
```

Now, add <NSURLConnectionDelegate> to the header of your class and implement the following methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
```

The first one should append the data, as shown below, and the final one should create and display the image.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
    // append the new data to the receivedData
    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for more details.

Comment: I hope this does not sound stupid but: i already am using NSURLConnection in the same class for another thing. so... how do i know the delegate methods are being called when doing one or the other thing and act accordingly?

Comment: the connection argument to your delegate methods will change.