# Loading image into the cache

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, caching, uiimage

I have following code for loading image from url in xml parsing endElement method :

```
food.image=strVal;
NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strVal]];
UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
food.myImage=image;
```

Although I am using this loaded images at the end of application,my application has to wait till all image get loaded. I supposed to use cache here but i am confused how to use the cache in this application. Is there any other way?

Comment: I can really suggest that you have a look at [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/) they hane a great extension on `UIImageView` to load and cache images.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149929/how-to-know-when-nsdatas-initwithcontentsofurl-has-finished-loading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code this will not create load on your main thread:-

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSData *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:yourURL]];
    UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [yourImageView setImage:image];

    });
});
```

Comment: i am getting exec_bad_access  at queue