# How do I get the file size to know whether it's download or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, download, file-handling

I am using following code for downloading epub /pdf from a url .I like to give a progress bar so when I start downloading it shows the progress and when the download completes it will popup a message. How can I implement this?

My code for downloading file

```
-(void)Download
 {
    NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    URLWithString:@"http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub"]];

    //Store the Data locally as epub  File if u want pdf change the file extension  

    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];

    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
 }
```

I am using this codes in my .m file but it's not working for me

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    _totalFileSize = response.expectedContentLength;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    _receivedDataBytes += [data length];
    MyProgressBar.progress = _receivedDataBytes / (float)_totalFileSize;
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14313172/1228669 may be this answer related to your question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add UIProgressView to a NSURLConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382075/add-uiprogressview-to-a-nsurlconnection)

Answer (score 2):

**use NSURLConnection**

**in .h file**

```
double datalength;
NSMutableData *databuffer;
UIProgressView *progress;
```

**in .m file**

```
-(void)Download
{
      NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub"]] delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
      [con start];
}
```

**delegate methods**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    datalength = [response expectedContentLength];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [databuffer appendData:data];
    progress.progress = (databuffer.length/datalength);
    self.HUD.detailsLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Downloading  %.f  %%",(databuffer.length/datalength)*100];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
    NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"3471.epub"];
    [pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
}
```

Comment: delegate methode in appdelege.m file ryt   a

Comment: naah.. in yourViewController.h ?? if you are using it from appDelegate then use that

Comment: i added ur ur .h code in my viewcontroller .h  ,, ur .m code in my download function inside .m file and  where i add delegate methodes?

Comment: in .m only you need to paste the delegate methods which i had written

Comment: REMOVE that no problem.. Its just MBProgressHUD

Comment: due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<GMMDetailpage 0x11372b30> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Pro_view1.'

Comment: some where you are setting wrong value for key... once check it

Answer (score 0):

If you do `curl -vvv -o epub.pdf http://www.feedbooks.com/book/3471.epub` you will see the following line:

`Content-Length: 603244`

The content-length header is the size in bytes of the data you are downloading.  You can use that to track your progress as you write your data.

With your current code, you can't really do what you want though.  You should check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149929/how-to-know-when-nsdatas-initwithcontentsofurl-has-finished-loading) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `data` length of NSData. Then you will find actual downloaded data.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
{
    // append the new data to the receivedData

    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

Here you will get length of data in bytes. You can convert it as per your need.

It may help you.